# SalesForce Bulk Api Error Occurs when Creating the Job in WSO2 ESB

Tags: xml, wso2, salesforce, esb, wso2-esb

Im using SalesforceBulkApi connector in WSO2 ESB to upload bulk object(Account) data to salesforce. Im getting InvalidJob error when testing the proxy service.

I have followed below WSO2 articles to configure SalesforceBulkApi.
                    *https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+Jobs+in+SalesforceBulk
                    *https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+Batches+in+SalesforceBulk*

I have created a test proxy service as following.
The below is the proxy service sample xml code.

```
 <salesforcebulk.init>
                                    <apiUrl>{$ctx:apiUrl}</apiUrl>
                                    <clientId>{$ctx:clientId}</clientId>
                                    <clientSecret>{$ctx:clientSecret}</clientSecret>
                                    <hostName>{$ctx:hostName}</hostName>
                                    <apiVersion>{$ctx:apiVersion}</apiVersion>
                                    <username>{$ctx:username}</username>
                                    <password>{$ctx:password}</password>
                                  </salesforcebulk.init>

                                 <salesforcebulk.createJob>
                                    <apiVersion>42</apiVersion>
                                    <accessToken>{$ctx:accessTokenValue}</accessToken>
                                    <apiUrl>{$ctx:apiUrl}</apiUrl>
                                    <clientId>{$ctx:clientId}</clientId>
                                    <clientSecret>{$ctx:clientSecret}</clientSecret>
                                    <intervalTime>1000000</intervalTime>
                                    <registryPath>connectors/SalesforceBulk</registryPath>
                                    <operation>insert</operation>
                                    <object>Account</object>
                                    <contentType>CSV</contentType>
                                </salesforcebulk.createJob>
```

The below Message formaters and builders are enabled in axix2.xml config file.

**Message Formatter in axix2.xml file.**

```
<messageFormatter contentType="text/csv" class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>
                    <messageFormatter contentType="zip/xml" class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>
                    <messageFormatter contentType="zip/csv" class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>
                    <messageFormatter contentType="text/xml" class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>
                    <messageFormatter contentType="text/html" class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>
                    <messageFormatter contentType="application/soap+xml" class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>
                    <messageFormatter contentType="application/xml" class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>
                    <messageFormatter contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" class="org.apache.synapse.commons.formatters.XFormURLEncodedFormatter"/>
                    <messageFormatter contentType="multipart/form-data" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.MultipartFormDataFormatter"/>
                    <messageFormatter contentType="application/xml" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ApplicationXMLFormatter"/>
                    <messageFormatter contentType="text/xml" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter"/>
                    <messageFormatter contentType="application/soap+xml" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter"/>
                    <messageFormatter contentType="text/plain" class="org.apache.axis2.format.PlainTextFormatter"/>


                   **Message Builders in axix2.xml file.**
                    <messageBuilder contentType="text/csv" class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>
                    <messageBuilder contentType="zip/xml" class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>
                    <messageBuilder contentType="zip/csv" class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>
                    <messageBuilder contentType="text/xml" class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>
                    <messageBuilder contentType="text/html" class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>
                    <messageBuilder contentType="application/soap+xml" class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>
                    <messageBuilder contentType="text/plain" class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>
                    <messageBuilder contentType="application/xml" class="org.apache.axis2.builder.ApplicationXMLBuilder"/>
                    <messageBuilder contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" class="org.apache.synapse.commons.builders.XFormURLEncodedBuilder"/>
                    <messageBuilder contentType="multipart/form-data" class="org.apache.axis2.builder.MultipartFormDataBuilder"/>
                    <messageBuilder contentType="text/plain" class="org.apache.axis2.format.PlainTextBuilder"/>
                    <messageBuilder contentType="application/json" class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder"/>
                    <messageBuilder contentType="application/xml" class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>
```

**But when testing the proxy service below error is generating,
                        
                           InvalidJob
                           Unable to parse Job
                          **

```
                    **Could someone tell me why is that error occurring.**
```

Answer (score 1):

This type of error, can be due to improper API name for the object.  For instance contact should be "Contact".  Also, remember the "__c" for custom objects.  But, I suspect this is a generic error that it couldn't figure out what was sent.